# Get Max +1 of VarChar Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which contains both text and numbers in a varchar column called EMPLOYEE_CODE. I want to ignore all the text and get the Highest number in the Column and then + 1 which i can then assign to a new employee. The code below would work on an INT Column but not on the VARCHAR because of the text i get the below error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'testusercode' to
>   data type int.

```
SELECT MAX(EMPLOYEE_CODE) + 1 as Target
FROM [COMPANY].[dbo].[USER]
WHERE EMPLOYEE_CODE + 1 NOT IN (SELECT EMPLOYEE_CODE From dbo.USER)
```

I am guessing I have to add convert or cast to the query but not sure how

Comment: please show some real EMPLOYEE_CODE data,or example

Comment: Hi Vec

The data looks like the below

1000
1001
1002
AD1
1003
1004
AD2
1005

Comment: This is a horrible design. Generating (supposedly) "unique" values like that won't work in a multi-user environment and is definitely not scalable. Use a sequence or identity column instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ISNUMERIC to check for number, get maximum value and add 1.

```
SELECT MAX(EMPLOYEE_CODE) + 1 as Target
FROM [COMPANY].[dbo].[USER]
WHERE  ISNUMERIC(EMPLOYEE_CODE) = 1
```

If you are using newer versions of SQL Server, you can also use

```
SELECT MAX(EMPLOYEE_CODE) + 1 as Target 
FROM [COMPANY].[dbo].[USER] WHERE TRY_PARSE(EMPLOYEE_CODE AS int) IS NOT NULL
```

There are TRY_CAST and TRY_CONVERT also for same stuff. You can easily check which one suits your purpose.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql

Comment: You have to change `'%[0-9]%'` to `'[0-9]+'` :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn pattern you are suggesting does not work. His condition is a special case where value will be only text like A-Za-z or only number 0-9, no special characters. If there will be values, which will be a mix of numbers are text, ISNUMERIC can be used simply to check numbers;

Comment: HI Amit

The first example returns 100 and the second returns an error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'TRN04' to data type int."

Comment: That means, you have column with mixed data. Please use the first one only. Updated the answer as well.

Comment: @Daniel can you provide sample data. Does your data contain other special characters, or currency symbols also.

Comment: The problem is that `ISNUMERIC` doesn't do what you want it to do. Since e.g. `£` and `1d1` are numeric, according to that function. (And correctly, given the definition of the function. The problem is that the function is useless from a practical perspective, given its definition)

Comment: @Amit Actually your code works perfectly, Appreciate your help

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks Damien that also works, i'll take not for future reference

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is also correct. ISNUMERIC holds currency values and real numbers also.That is why it will say 1d1 is correct and also e0 is correct. But in your case, it will be text mixed with numbers. So, both work. In general, people working with SQL don't like ISNUMERIC too much. It has too many features and its scope is not very specific. That's why they introduced TRY_PARSE etc. It WILL WORK in your scenario well. Check more ISNUMERIC features (or shortcomings) here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272(v=sql.110).aspx